# What is meant by coordinate time? Isn't it time measured on a clock? If not then what does it measure?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, time, definition, observers

In this question-

[Is proper time equal to the Invariant Interval or the time elapsed in the Rest Frame?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/602865/113699)

@Dale in the comments says-

> no $dt$ is never physical time. It is always coordinate time. The equation $d\tau=dt’$ needs to be interpreted carefully. It is not a general fact, but instead it is only true along the worldline of the clock and only in the (primed) rest frame of said clock. But even then, the physical time is $d\tau$ and the coordinate time $dt’$ is designed to match it. That is what makes the primed coordinates the rest frame of the clock [...]

*What is coordinate time?*

**What does one mean by coordinate time? Isn't it a time measured on the clock ( any clock)?**

@Dale says no.

**Then what is meant coordinate time?**

Comment: Time is measured on a clock. But whose clock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In relativity we deal with spacetime which is a 4-dimensional structure called a (pseudo-Riemannian) manifold. It includes space and time together. Meaning that time is just another direction in spacetime, perpendicular to the three dimensions of space.

In the manifold we have a metric which describes all of the geometric properties of spacetime. It describes physically measured distances and durations and angles and speeds. You can use it to identify straight or curved lines and so forth. Straight lines in this sense are technically called geodesics.

A point particle forms a line in the spacetime manifold, called its worldline. An extended object forms a worldsheet or a worldtube, but we will stick with worldlines for now. A physically measured duration is called proper time, $d\tau$, and is measured by a physical clock on a specified worldline. An inertial object (in free-fall, no real forces acting on it) moves in a straight line at constant speed according to Newton’s first law. In other words, an inertial object’s worldline is straight.

Now, spacetime does not come with any physical labels or grid lines on it, but often we find it convenient to add labels/gridlines. These are called coordinates. Coordinates are ordered set of four numbers that label each event in spacetime. They must have some nice mathematical properties like being smooth and invertible. Everything else is a matter of convenience.

One approach that is often convenient is to use the first coordinate for time and the last three coordinates for space $(t,x,y,z)$. A further convenience is to use straight lines and planes. A further convenience is to choose an inertial object as a reference and orient those lines so that the time coordinate axis is parallel with the reference object’s worldline and so that the space axes remain fixed and don’t rotate. A final convenience is to scale the coordinates so that on the reference object’s worldline the physically measured proper time matches the coordinate time and so that coordinate distances match measured physical distances. Such coordinates are called the inertial reference object’s rest frame. In the absence of gravity such coordinates can extend to cover all of spacetime, but with gravity they can only be local, near the path of the inertial object.

Importantly, *in these coordinates* the metric can be written as $ds^2 = -c^2 d\tau^2 = -c^2 dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. The physical time measured on any clock can be obtained by integrating the above expression for $d\tau$ along the worldline of that clock. The coordinate time is merely a convention for assigning the labels as described above. This convention is chosen to match the physical time on the reference object’s clock, but not necessarily on other clocks. Elsewhere, $dt$ is merely a label.

Comment: If I have understood correctly then in the Schwarzschild metric case -$(1-R/r) dt$ ( not just dt but it's coefficient included) measures the physical time and similarly $(1-R/r) ^{-1}dr$ measures the physical distance just like in the Minkowski metric case $cdt$ would give the exact physical time and $dx$ or $r^d\theta$ would give the physical distance. Is that right. Have what I understood now correct. That means when the $g_{00} =1$ then $dt$ alone would represent physical time but when $g_{00}\neq 1$ then the entire $g_{00}dt$ ( dt together with the coefficient) represents the physical time

Comment: @Shashaank for a stationary clock, yes. Not for moving clocks.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Finally. To finish off- 1) for moving clocks the physical time is $(1-R/r)dt^2 + (all the spacelike terms with corresponding metric coefficients)$ and the physical distances in $r, \theta , \phi $ directions are just $(1-R/r)^{-1}dr$ and the corresponding terms for $\theta$ and $\phi$.. 2) And the gravitation time dilation relation ( for stationary clocks) is to be just understood as a relation between proper times ($d\tau_1$ and $d\tau_2$ ) at two different places (r_1, r_2) in the manifold ( which is a bit different than the SR one).Are the above statements correct, pls confirm

Comment: @Shashaank for 1) yes, although it is easier to write it $d\tau$. 2) no, time dilation is the relationship between proper time and coordinate time at the same location. So $\gamma = dt/d\tau$

Comment: Thanks. But in 2) what you said is good in SR. In GR for clocks at rest,$d\tau = (1-R/r)^{1/2}dt$, I was thinking that since proper time is the physically meaningful thing ( time elapsed),it would be more meaningful to compare$d\tau_1=(1-R/r_1) ^{1/2}dt$ and $d\tau_2=(1-R/r_2) ^{1/2}dt$ and then say that time (physical time that is proper time) passes slowly for the same coordinate time difference (which is a somewhat abstract thing/coordinate) when you are deeper in the gravitational well than when you are far away from the gravitational source. Even Weinberg says so.Isn't it sensibly correct

Comment: @Shashaank comments are for improving the question, not for discussion. You really need to go to a site that is more conducive for discussion. I agree that what you describe is more physically meaningful, but it is called redshift, not time dilation. Redshift is directly measurable as the change in the frequency of light emitted by one object and received at another. If redshift is measured between two stationary objects then it is called gravitational redshift. If the objects are moving then it includes Doppler redshift.

Comment: Be careful in your definitions. "...time is just another direction in spacetime, perpendicular to the three dimensions of space. This mathematical structure is called a manifold." is not a great definition. There is no sense in which time is "perpendicular" to the space dimensions without a metric, and as such is therefore also a metric-dependent quality. It also reads like you are saying that only spacetime is a manifold and that the spatial-only submanifold is not.

Comment: "An inertial object (no forces acting on it) moves in a straight line at constant speed according to Newton’s first law. In other words, an inertial object’s worldline is straight." I would not use the word "straight" because it might cause confusion. Inertial objects move along Euclidean paths since the point of GR is that _all_ objects always move along straight paths.

Comment: @Zorawar it is a loose non-technical description, not a definition. Also, the metric is an inherent part of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold, so loose descriptions that rely on features of the metric are acceptable IMO. “the point of GR is that all objects always move along straight paths” is not at all correct. Only inertial objects move along straight paths (where “straight” is understood as “geodesic”)

Comment: Yes, I didn't quibble about manifolds having metrics from a strict mathematical point of view, so l think saying that manifolds have an inherent metric is fine from a physical point of view. But mentioning "perpendicular" is neither correct nor necessary. It is only _locally_ perpendicular, in general, and this is a physical requirement. I would recommend just dropping "perpendicular" completely: for anybody asking such essential questions of relativity, this will just be liable to confuse them. Like I said, it's not even necessary to mention here.

Comment: @Dale I agree with your comment on Zorawar. Physics forum doesn't allow me to register but I am happy that atleast I was thinking about a thing that is more meaningful just that it is called by a different name. I will ask another question here regarding the difference between gravitational redshirt and gravitational time dilation. I will be happy to read your views there if you'd like to answer. Thanks.

Comment: "where _straight_ is understood as _geodesic_" is exactly the issue. The point you are making above is not that it is a straight path, since all objects in GR move along straight (geodesic) paths, but that it is Euclidean. Again, avoid using "straight" here so that you don't confuse people for whom these concepts are new.

Comment: Note that: "Only inertial objects move along straight paths (where _straight_ is understood as _geodesic_)" is not correct. You probably just wrote that wrong. _All_ objects move geodesically (i.e., straight); only inertial objects move along Euclidean paths.

Comment: @Zorawar “all objects in GR move along straight (geodesic) paths” this is incorrect. Only inertial (free falling) objects move on geodesics. Non inertial objects do not travel on geodesics. You are currently probably not in free fall and so not moving on a straight path in GR. See Carroll’s Lecture Notes on p 70: https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019 “The primary usefulness of geodesics in general relativity is that they are the paths fol- lowed by unaccelerated particles. In fact, the geodesic equation can be thought of as the generalization of Newton’s law f = ma for the case f = 0”

Comment: Again, you need to be careful here. If you say "An inertial object (no forces acting on it) moves in a straight line at constant speed according to Newton’s first law." then a free-falling object is not inertial since it does not move at constant speed. At least, not the way that you've set it up. As I said before, you need to add locality to this definition to make it better (see p. 72 of the same notes). As you've worded it, it sounds like "inertial" is being defined as it is in SR, which is why I said you should say "Euclidean" and not "straight".

Comment: Also, don't confuse when I say all objects move geodesically with non-gravitational effects: I'm talking about pure gravity only. I interpreted your definition above as defining inertial as in SR, in which case all (pure-gravitational) paths are geodesic, and "inertial" are Euclidean. I would be careful using the more general definition of inertial and _not_ defining it in terms of free-falling objects.

Comment: @Zorawar I am sorry but I do not like your proposed terminology at all. It surprises me that you think it is acceptable to write “all paths” and mean “only pure-gravitational paths” and yet object to “perpendicular” which is a perfectly valid way to describe a tetrad. I also do not think the word “Euclidean” belongs anywhere in a discussion about pseudo-Riemannian manifolds (except maybe “not Euclidean”). Your terminology does not at all seem to be an improvement. I have no intention to alter my answer as suggested. The only suggestion that seems palatable is “locally”. I will consider that.

Comment: Euclidean/pseudo-Euclidean, fine I'm being sloppy. Wick rotate and it makes no difference for my purpose, which is that if you say inertial frames are constant velocity, then you are implying a distinction between flat trajectories and geodesics on curved manifolds when you call the former "straight". If you mean geodesic always, and so define "inertial" as for free-falling bodies, then you must clarify that it is only flat _locally_ -- it is only constant-velocity _locally_. What you wrote was misleading for what you meant.

Comment: @Zorawar said “if you say inertial frames are constant velocity ...”. Which I did not say. I am done with my revisions. I do not like most of your terminology and I will not make further modifications at your recommendation. I am done responding to your posts. Feel free to leave the last comment.

Answer (score 6):

In special relativity one traditionally imagines that spacetime is filled with a network of clocks that are Einstein synchronized. The clocks define an inertial reference frame, and the time coordinate of an event is the reading on the nearest clock.

When dealing with curved spacetime you usually can't Einstein synchronize clocks, and it's usually not convenient to use clock readings (however synchronized) directly as a coordinate, so coordinates are treated more abstractly. The same is true when dealing with ordinary curved surfaces like the surface of the Earth. We use latitude and longitude to measure global position, but there are no rulers that measure latitude and longitude; measurements are done locally with metersticks. In general relativity, the metric tells you how to convert between local measurements of clocks and metersticks and the global coordinates that you're using.

Comment: If I have understood correctly then in the Schwarzschild metric case -$(1-R/r) dt$ ( not just dt but it's coefficient included) measures the physical time and similarly $(1-R/r) ^{-1}dr$ measures the physical distance just like in the Minkowski metric case $cdt$ would give the exact physical time and $dx$ or $r^d\theta$ would give the physical distance. Is that right. Have what I understood now correct. That means when the $g_{00} =1$ then $dt$ alone would represent physical time but when $g_{00}\neq 1$ then the entire $g_{00}dt$ ( dt together with the coefficient) represents the physical time

Comment: This looks to me by far the best explained answer. Please just confirm the above comment I have put. Also it would be really helpful if you could please elaborate the last sentence in your answer mathematically i.e please elaborate mathematically a bit on "the metric tells you how........ the global coordinates that you're using." I think it will be perfect then. Thanks

Comment: Could you please confirm the above point.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematically Space-Time is a 4-dimensional Lorentzian manifold $L$. Coordinates of an event,
i.e. $(x_{\mu})=(ct, x, y, z)$ only make sense when you define an Atlas $\mathcal{A}={(\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha})}$ on $L$ where
$\mathcal{U}_{\alpha}\subset L$ and $\phi_{\alpha}:L\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$  is a homeomorphism (i.e. continus functions between the topological Spaces $M$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$). The coordinates of a point $p\in U_{\alpha}\subset L$ are then given by $\phi_{\alpha}(p)=(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$.

There are a few restrictions on the $\phi_{\alpha}$ in order for the math to make sense, but other than that you're more or less free to choose any parametrization you want. The main idea is now, that physical quantities and laws should in a sense be independent of this choice. $\tau$ is such a quantity, the coordinates $x_i=\phi_{\alpha}(p)_i$ are obviously not.

Answer (score 2):

$d\tau$ is an invariant of the metric. $dt$ is the time measured by a clock in a particular frame, as $dx$ is the length measured in this frame.

It is like saying that in 2D spatial cartesian coordinates, $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$. $ds$ here is invariant by rotation. And we can also say that for any orientation of $ds$, there is a particular frame so that $ds^2 = dx^2$ (or $ds^2 = dy^2$).

But for 2D polar coordinates it is different. $ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\theta^2$. $ds$ is also invariant by rotation. But there is no angle of rotation that leads to $ds^2 = d\theta^2$. It only happens in the case of $r = 1$. It corresponds to the example of $d\tau = dt$ for a static observer in the Schwartschild metric, that is only valid at $r = \infty$.

The Minkowski metric can be compared to the example of cartesian coordinates, and $d\tau$ can be understood as the time for a clock at rest of an inertial frame.

But in GR, similar to the example of polar coordinates, it is not generally true.

Comment: If I have understood correctly then in the Schwarzschild metric case -$(1-R/r) dt$ ( not just dt but it's coefficient included) measures the physical time and similarly $(1-R/r) ^{-1}dr$ measures the physical distance just like in the Minkowski metric case $cdt$ would give the exact physical time and $dx$ or $r^d\theta$ would give the physical distance. Is that right. Have what I understood now correct. That means ever the $g_{00} =1$ then $dt$ alone would represent physical time but when $g_{00}\neq 1$ then the entire $g_{00}dt$ ( dt together with the coefficient) represents the physical time

Comment: Could you please confirm the above point.

Comment: Yes, as already answered by Dale. It is the same principle for measuring a distance between 2 points in an open landscape. It is possible to use some topographic device and make a local direct measurement. Or use GPS to get the ccordinates of each point, and make a calculation to get the distance. The spacetime metric is the rule to calculate not only distance between points, but time between events. And that must coincide with a local measurement by metersticks or clocks.

Comment: Thanks I understand now. But your last line in the above comment is a bit confusing to me. I am a bit confused what do you mean by the last and the 2nd last line. Could you please add a mathematical equation regarding your last line "And that must coincide.......... metersticks or clocks". It will be perfect then, I guess. Thanks again

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski Sorry for nitpicking, but distances and times are defined along some paths, not between two events.

Comment: @Shashaank The distances and clocks are defined along some worldlines, not only between points and events. So if you have a curve $\gamma(\lambda)$ given by coordinates $x^\mu(\lambda)$ from A to B, then if it is spacelike you can compute distance by $d=\int_A^B\sqrt{g_{\mu\nu}x'^\mu x'^\nu}d\lambda,$ where $x'^\mu$ is derivative of $\mu$-coordinate wrt $\lambda$. If the curve is timelike, then the proper time is $\tau=\int_A^B\sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu}x'^\mu x'^\nu}d\lambda.$ (in units with $c=1$). This numbers should be the same as the one your physically measure along the curve.

Comment: @Umaxo Thank I understand this. I am happy with this. But what does Claudio mean by "... Coincide with a local measurement.... ".. What does that mean in terms of a mathematical equation. I am bit confused here.

Comment: @Shashaank I cannot speak for Claudio, but didn't I just answered it? I did not used locality, but other than that I told you how can you calculate from coordinates and metric the results of your measurements with real metersticks and clocks.

Comment: @Umaxo yeh sure I understood that. I guess doing local measurements is just compounding small measurements which could do with each $\eta$ in Lorentz Local frames and then add all these to get what you have written. Like $ds^2= \eta_{mu nu}\dot{x^mu}\dot{x^nu}$ will hold in only a small region. To get what you have written you just need to compound all these local results. Right...

Comment: @Umaxo you are right. But my example for comparison is a small distance $\Delta s$ that can be computed using longitudes and latitudes from GPS positions of two points, or directly measuring it. A path is a sum of that distances, when $ds$ tends to zero.